# Great Circle Distance Formula in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, great-circle

I need to calculate distance between Latitude and Longitude using Great Circle Formula.

One way I know, is to use the following:

```
 CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
```

But, I am not sure if it used Great Circle Distance algorithm for calculations. Does anyone have any idea about this? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: google maps use the great circle distance formula and apple follows the curvature of the Earth formula to find out the distance

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `distanceFromLocation:` is quite clear:

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations.

Yes, this is the [Great Circle Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (CGFloat)directMetersFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)from toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)to {

static const double DEG_TO_RAD = 0.017453292519943295769236907684886;  
static const double EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 6372797.560856;  

double latitudeArc  = (from.latitude - to.latitude) * DEG_TO_RAD;
double longitudeArc = (from.longitude - to.longitude) * DEG_TO_RAD;
double latitudeH = sin(latitudeArc * 0.5);
latitudeH *= latitudeH;
double lontitudeH = sin(longitudeArc * 0.5);
lontitudeH *= lontitudeH;
double tmp = cos(from.latitude*DEG_TO_RAD) * cos(to.latitude*DEG_TO_RAD);
return EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS * 2.0 * asin(sqrt(latitudeH + tmp*lontitudeH));}
```

Source: [Distance between two points on Globe](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_distance_between_two_points_on_a_globe#Objective_C)